# Send data on a JSON server using react

Tags: reactjs, json

am trying to send a post request to a JSON server using react. I've captured the data from a form using react formik. When I try to make a post request, the server only creates an id but the rest of the data is not captured. I've tried logging out the data just before the fetch method and it appears. It's only the server that is not picking it.

Below is the submit method from formik.

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
  console.log(values)
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
      headers: {"Contect-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
  }).then(responce => {
      if (!responce.ok) {
          alert("Failed to add")
      }else{
          alert("Contact added")
      }
      return responce.json();
  }).then(data => {
      console.log('Added')

  })
}
```

Comment: Can you post the log as well ?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What is the output?

Comment: When I run the code, the data is not sent to the server, a new object is created with only the id. The rest of the data is not passed